# How to open a file in Far Manager's external editor inside Conemu New Tab?

Tags: conemu, sublime-text-3

I am using Far Manager and Conemu. I browse through far manager and i want to edit a file with Far Manager's F4 command (External Editor) but i want it to open the file inside a new Tab in Conemu.

For e.g.

I have selected Sublime Text 3 as the external editor inside Far Manager, when i press F4, the open is opened but it opens in Sublime Text 3 Editor and not inside Conemu Tab.

Is there a way to open the file inside Conemu's Tab using Sublime text as the editor in the new tab ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `-new_console` argument to your editor command line. Read about in [Wiki](http://code.google.com/p/conemu-maximus5/wiki/NewConsole).

Example

```
 Notepad.exe "!\!.!" -new_console
```

Comment: Where can i find the !\!.! command ?

Comment: Where? Have you read Far Manager F1?

Comment: Yes, but i guess i might have missed it.

Comment: F1, "Special symbols". All there. "!\" and "!.!"

Comment: i did use those but i did not know that we could use multiple symbols inside double quotes.